# NodeJS socket connection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, lamp

I'm trying to create a live web chat system using Socket.io but i'm using it alongside a LAMP stack also. At the moment I am just trying to get my HTML page to recognize connections on localhost:8888 but the server side on localhost:3000 should be console logging the below when somebody connects, but i'm getting nothing?

I have this on my server side -

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

This is my client side -

```
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>

  var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');

    socket.on('connection', function(io){
      console.log('a user connected');
      io.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
    });               


  </script>
```

I'm not seeing any of the console logs? Am I calling it wrong or

Answer (score 0):

On client side connection event called 'connect'. You have moved client listener to server in example from socke.io, but events for client and server is different, more there: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('a user connected');
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand..?

Comment: I've added some code that works. API for server and client side is different. Be carefult and check it by API docs on socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You need to have code on the sever to listen for connections.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

See the docs for more info http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: This hasn't worked, can't understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: When you run the app by typing node app.js or whatever your file is called does it give you an error or does it print "listening on *:3000"?

Comment: it prints "listening on *:3000"

Comment: No other errors(client side)? Make sure you are including the socket.io client script.  You should be able to copy paste the client and server and it should work right away.